# RabbitMQ doesn't have any queue, how to solve it?

Tags: magento2, server-setup, rabbit-mq, message-queue

I have RabbitMQ installed and configured, but when I run this command below I receive a message saying **No items**.

```
python3 /usr/bin/rabbitmqadmin --host rabbitmq -u username -p 8b2sovjbgg4atsbpn0s0oam9y6vekh6i list queues
```

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no queue because after installing RabbitMQ probably you didn't run the setup upgrade, try to run it, compile your Magento and clean up the cache again.

```
bin/magento s:upgrade
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
bin/magento c:flush
```